# clipboard.js hover for tables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using clipboard.js to display a button that will allow a user to copy the specific table that the mouse is hovering over. I got it to work for one table, but I need it to work for two. Here is what I have so far:

**JS**

```
new ClipboardJS('.btn');

var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
             e.clearSelection();
});
```

**HTML**
    **Table 1**

```
 <div class="container">             
 <h3>Table 1</h3>
 <div id="table1" class="table1">       

   <div class="overlay">
   <button type ="btn" class="btn btn-default pull-right tooltip" title="Copied!" style="display:none;" data-clipboard-target="#table1">
    <img src="clippy.png" width="20px" title="Copy to clipboard">
   </button>
   </div> 

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.table1', function () {
                        $(this).find(":button").show();
                    }).on('mouseleave', '.table1', function () {
                        $(this).find(":button").hide();
                    });
                });
   </script>



    <!-- TABLE 1 -->    
    <table>

    </table>
    <!-- END TABLE 1 -->
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Table 2**

```
   <div class="container">                       
   <h3>Table 2</h3>
   <div id="table2" class="table2">


   <div class="overlay">
   <button type ="btn" class="btn btn-default pull-right tooltip" title="Copied!" style="display:none;" data-clipboard-target="#table2">
    <img src="clippy.png" width="20px" title="Copy to clipboard">
   </button>
   </div> 

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.table2', function () {
                        $(this).find(":button").show();
                    }).on('mouseleave', '.table2', function () {
                        $(this).find(":button").hide();
                    });
                });
   </script>



    <!-- TABLE 2 -->    
    <table>

    </table>
    <!-- END TABLE 2 -->
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.overlay:before{
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 15%;
 }
```

The hover works but it does not go away unless I am off the page rather than off the table and only one hover shows. I would like a button for each table. Could someone help? Also, if you are so kind to offer your help could you please post the code here instead of JSFiddle? I'm on my work computer at the moment and it has been blocked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues I have found here:

First: your buttons seem to be on the same place, this is why you only see one of them. This also makes the hover handle weirdly.

Change the CSS to:

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
}
```

Second, you can factorize all events into one jQuery call by using the same class for the containers.

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Table 1</h3>
  <div id="table1" class="table">

    <div class="overlay">
      <button style="display:none;">Button A</button>
    </div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Table 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Table 2</h3>
  <div id="table2" class="table">

    <div class="overlay">
      <button style="display:none">Button B</button>
    </div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Table 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.table', function() {
      $(this).find("button").show();
    }).on('mouseleave', '.table', function() {
      $(this).find(":button").hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. One thing that bothers me is when I hover, the table shifts down for the button. `overlay{position: absolute;}` gives me the effect that I want without moving the tables but still only shows the button in one place. Is there an alternative to `overlay{position: relative;}` that won't move the tables or should I just try to work with it?

Comment: You can set the `position: relative` to `.table` and then switch `.overlay` back to `position: absolute`. Absolute elements are positioned to the closest parent which has a `position` attribute set.

Comment: Thanks again I really appreciate it!